# How is raw mouse movement converted to /dev/input/mice content?

Tags: linux, kernel, usb, mouse

Raw mouse movement is generating some data and sent via USB. It is then getting processed somewhere and written into /dev/input/mice & supplied to GUI, etc.

How is this happening? If I want to keep a USB Mouse as unknown USB Data Stream and read from it - how is it done?

Answer (score 3):

Your mouse presents itself as a **HID** (Human interface device) usb class device. You can remove the device from the kernel HID driver's control by finding the hex vendor and device id of it and giving it to libhid-detach-device. Eg:

```
lsusb
...
Bus 003 Device 013: ID 046d:c05a Logitech, Inc. M90/M100 Optical Mouse
...
sudo libhid-detach-device 046d:c05a
```